# Java 8 cyclic inference warning

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

My knowledge about list operations is from scripting languages. So in Java I stopped on something strange in case of finding cookie with particular name.

```
List<Cookie> cookies = Arrays.asList(request.getCookies());
        String auth = cookies.stream()
                .filter(c -> c.getName().equals("auth"))
                .map(Cookie::getValue);
```

On the `map` method IntelliJ is showing me "Cyclic inference".

> Java compiler Error:(52, 25) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that java.util.stream.Stream conforms to java.lang.String

Comment: As the message says, `map` returns a `Stream` and can’t be assigned to a `String`. You have to tell how it should become a single `String`. Maybe you want to use `.findAny().get()`?

Comment: Nice question and answer but I still don't know what a cyclic inference is! Will keep Googling, this was the first result.

Comment: @JimLohse This answer explains what cyclic inference is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36258012/3142816. Basically, type of inner subexpression can't be inferred without type of outer subexpression, which can't be inferred without type of inner subexpression

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your current code returns a `Stream<String>`, so you need an extra step to return a string:

```
Optional<String> auth = cookies.stream()
            .filter(c -> c.getName().equals("auth"))
            .map(Cookie::getValue)
            .findAny();
```

Note that it returns an `Optional<String>` because there may be no Cookie that matches "auth". If you want to use a default if "auth" is not found you can use:

```
String auth = cookies.stream()
            .filter(c -> c.getName().equals("auth"))
            .map(Cookie::getValue)
            .findAny().orElse("");
```

Answer (score 0):

In essence, what this rather cryptic error message is saying is "the output of the stream sequence doesn't match what you are assigning it to in the end", ex:

```
String s = list.stream().map(s -> s); // this doesn't result in a String...
```

.findFirst().get()
So to debug compilation, remove the assignment (temporarily), or, as the other answer says, add something that makes it return a String by collecting (ex: `.collect(Collectors.joining(","))`) or (getting like `.findFirst().get()`), or change the assignment, like `Stream<String> stream = list.stream().map(...)`