# Java Lambda Cyclic inference

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

I have problem with Java Lambda Expressions. I am use Spring 4, JdbcTemplate, Java 8. Intellij IDEA show "Cyclic inference". What is it and how fix it? Thank you for attention.

```
@Override
public User getUser(long id) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?",
            ps -> {
                ps.setLong(1, id);
            },
            (rs, rowNum) -> {
                return new User(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getLong(4), rs.getBoolean(5));
            });
}
```

[image]

**Solved**
This function return  List, not User. And correct function is this:

```
@Override
public User getUser(long id) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?",
            ps -> {
                ps.setLong(1, id);
            },
            (rs, rowNum) -> {
                return new User(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getLong(4), rs.getBoolean(5));
            }).get(0);
}
```

Comment: sceenshot missing :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [java 8 cyclic inference in my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422166/java-8-cyclic-inference-in-my-case)

Comment: What IntelliJ version do you have?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 14 Ultimate

Comment: Do you see any difference between these two pieces of code? Not me.

Comment: Part1 returns List<User>.

Part2 returns instance of User of List<User> with index 0.

Comment: It seems, that you has made dangerous way of return. If there are no objects, it has to throw null pointer. I think this way is safe and comfortable:list.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);

Comment: Ján Яabčan, I agree with you. But then I didn't know Stream API in Java 8 well. Thank you.

Comment: If it's really solved then [post it as an answer, this is OK to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) and @BinkanSalaryman this must be the "cyclic inference" the two answers point at each other1

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public User getUser(long id) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?",
            ps -> {
                ps.setLong(1, id);
            },
            (rs, rowNum) -> {
                return new User(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getLong(4), rs.getBoolean(5));
            }).stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Or you can use also .findAny instead of findFirst.