# Collectors::toList cyclic inference

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In the following code Intellij says "Cyclic inference"

```
List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
rows.add("12345");
rows.add("123");
rows.add("123456");
rows = rows.stream().filter(e -> e.length() > 4).collect(Collectors::toList);
rows.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

There must be some problems with `Collectors::toList` which I can't uderstand.

Comment: Looking at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422166/java-8-cyclic-inference-in-my-case, looks like you're assigning `rows.stream().filter(e -> e.length() > 4).collect(Collectors::toList)` which is not List<String>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`collect` expects `Collector` which is not functional interface so you can't use lambda or method reference to provide its implementation.

You simply need to use `Collectors.toList()` which returns Collector instance which collects your elements in list.

Comment: What does this mean "not a functional interface" ?  `Collectors.toList()` is part of streams that came in Java8 only .. so does that mean streams are not functional? I'm unaware of this nomenclature and dichotomy.

Comment: @javadba Functional interface is an interface which has one abstract method. Point of lambda or method reference is to provide implementation for this method. Visit http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-is-a-functional-interface/ for more info on this subject and many others related to lambdas.