# Populate a map conditionally using streams - Java 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to translate this (simplified) code to use Java-8 streams:

```
Map<String, String> files = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

while(((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      if(content != null)
        files.put("not null"+line, "not null"+line);
      else
        files.put("its null"+line, "its null"+line);
    }
reader.close();
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
files = reader.lines().parallel().collect((content != null)?
                (Collectors.toConcurrentMap(line->"notnull"+line, line->line+"notnull")) :                                              
                (Collectors.toConcurrentMap(line->line+"null", line->line+"null")));
```

But the above gives a "cyclic inference" message for all the `line->line+"..."` on intelliJ. What is cyclic inference? Is there an error in this logic?

I noted some similar issues on SO. But they suggest to use interface(Map) instead of its implementations. But `files` here is declared as a `Map`.

Update: Adding more context, `content` is a String that holds the name of a directory. `files` is a map that holds multiple file paths. What file paths need to go into the `files` map depends on `content` directory-name is populated or not.

Comment: The code sample is a bit unclear. (1) What is the "content" variable? (2) Are you reading lines of a single file, but putting them into a map called "files"?

Comment: 1. `content` is a String that holds a name of a directory.
2. Yes, I'm reading lines from a text file(basically contains some partial tokens) and appending it to file paths which will together go into files map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to fix this is to introduce the intermediate variable for collector:

```
Collector<String, ?, ConcurrentMap<String, String>> collector = (content != null) ?
        (Collectors.toConcurrentMap(line->"notnull"+line, line->line+"notnull")) :
        (Collectors.toConcurrentMap(line->line+"null", line->line+"null"));
Map<String, String> files = reader.lines().parallel().collect(collector);
```

This solution (unlike one presented by @JanXMarek) does not allocate intermediate arrays and does not check the `content` for every input line.

The cyclic inference is the situation in the type inference procedure when to determine the type of inner subexpression, the type of outer subexpression must be determined, but it cannot be determined without knowing the type of inner subexpression. Type inference in Java-8 can infer that in case of `Stream<String>.collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(line->line+"null", line->line+"null"))` the type of Collector is `Collector<String, ?, ConcurrentMap<String, String>>`. Normally when subexpression type (here we're speaking about `toConcurrentMap(...)` subexpression) cannot be explicitly determined, it can be reduced using the outer context if the outer context is method invocation, cast or assignment. Here however the outer context is `?:` operator which has its own complex type inference rules, so this becomes too much and you should help the type inference system specifying the explicit type somewhere.

Comment: I think this solution is much more readable and efficient, given that you aren't dynamically allocating much memory.

Comment: I like this solution, however, I would have moved the ternary operator to `keyMapper` and `valueMapper` functions definition, and would have used those in `Collectors.toConcurrentMap`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this

```
reader.lines().parallel()
    .map(line -> content == null ?
            new String[]{"notnull"+line, line+"notnull"} :
            new String[]{line+"null", line+"null"})
    .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(pair -> pair[0], pair -> pair[1]));
```

First, you **map** the line to a (key,value) pair stored in an array (or in some kind of a Pair object), and then, in the collector, you split it again into a key and a value.

Comment: Thanks @Jan. How would it know that `pair` is a String array? Should I declare it within the `toConcurrentMap()` ?  I think the .map() should pass the String array into the `pair` variable but I'm getting an error saying its not defined.

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed a typo in my code. But you do not need to declare the type anywhere. Java compiler infers it from the result of the map() operation. You can just copy-paste my code and it should work (as long a the "reader" and "content"  variables are defined). If not, what error exactly are you getting?

Comment: I'm still curious what is cyclic inference. Can anyone throw some light on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just a side-note. I doubt that .parallel() is of any good in this context. If you are using the standard Java API for reading files, the iterator underneath will still read the file sequentially. The only thing that will be executed in parallel will be transforming the lines. I just tried it on my PC, out of my curiosity, and it was about 10% faster without .parallel().

Parallelisation makes sense if the processing is an order of magnitude slower than reading the input of the stream, which is not the case here.

Comment: Hi Jan, just to be clear, did you try `parallel()` + `toConcurrentMap()` combination vs. non-parallel + `toMap()` combination?  and you found that non-parallel+toMap() worked faster?

Comment: I parallel vs non-parallel to ConcurrentMap, and the input was a file of about 100K lines. Well, it may behave differently on a different hardware or OS. Maybe you will experience 10% gain with parallelism on your system in this case. My point was that .parallell() is not a free beer. Even if you have an 8 core processor, it will not behave any better than non-parallell stream for 93.73547% of the real cases, due to the Ahmdal law, which always lurks somewhere.